# Execution speed testing

Tags: c++, performance, posix, measure

Hello everyone lets say i have something like this :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

void
test()
{
    /* Some tests */
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
    }
}

void
testing(void(*tester)())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        struct timeval start;
        struct timeval stop;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        (*tester)();
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
        usleep(2000);
        std::cout << (float)((stop.tv_sec * (int)1e6 + stop.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * (int)1e6 + start.tv_usec)) << std::endl;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    testing(&test);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am measuring the execution time of a function, can someone explain to me why usleep can have an impact on the time I am measuring here? Since it is outside the critical measurement zone?

Comment: Why do you think it is affecting the result? Do you have outputs from runs with and without the usleep?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah i have some different outputs indeed.

Comment: I think the idea is to *post* the results.

Comment: Nothing interesting except that with usleep I only have 1, 2 and a few crumbs of ">10", and without I only have 1 and 2. I would like to understand @WeatherVane

Comment: Let readers be the judge of that. as posted you are doing 1000 of something unknown.

Comment: @WeatherVane https://pastebin.com/5PnMubwT https://pastebin.com/AcT1bN6K
Both output

Comment: Please post information *in the question*. It's quite simple, please post a few sample timings.

Comment: Sleeping reduces the load on the CPU so a typical governor will scale down the frequency.

Comment: @rustyx In simpler terms? aha

Comment: Modern CPU has [Dynamic Frequency Scaling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THbnQcv66bo). It slows down when there's no work and speeds up when there's a lot of work. But scaling up takes time. So immediately after a sleep it will take some time to speed up.

Comment: Interesting @rustyx

Comment: Remember to build with compiler optimizations enabled when doing performance testing.

Comment: The frequency scaling is likely the main reason. A second one (less significant) is the overhead of context switches that can cause caches misses and the flush of the prediction table (modern processors predict the branches taken so to reduce the overhead of condition/loops).